# How to redirect from IIS an URL with parameters

Tags: php, iis, redirect, url-parameters

I have a wordpress blog deployed in my IIS 6. I would like to redirect the URL:

www.myblog.com/index.php/2012/03/**14**/notes

to

www.myblog.com/index.php/2012/03/**12**/notes

Is there any way to do it by using IIS or I shall modify the php code? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/), it's a powerful regular-expressions-based URL rewriter for IIS.

you can use something like :

> RewriteBase /
>
> RewriteRule ^(.+)/14/notes/(.+)$ $1/12/notes/$2 [NC,R=301,L